# What's the deal with the 18ga wire in a light fixture?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, wire

I always read "rule #1: never use less than 14GA wire on a 15A breaker, and never use less than 12GA wire on a 20A breaker". The idea being that if the circuit gets to the max current allowed by the breaker, too small of wire can get too hot.

So recently I installed a direct-wire light fixture, and attached to the light and switch on the fixture where they wanted me to connect power were 18GA wires. So, excited about my new fixture, I connected my 14GA from the wall to the 18GA wires in the fixture, buttoned it all up, enjoyed my new light, but now am wondering "what was I supposed to do to not violate rule #1?".

It is "ok" for the wire to potentially get hot as long as it's in a metal fixture or something (vs in the drywall)? Or is it "ok" for the wire to get hot because it is onl 10" (presumably not?)? What gives??

Comment: Ah ok, so the idea is just that the fixture (by design/hope? haha) will draw a maximum current that is much smaller than 15A.

Comment: Wires inside walls generally always have to be 14 AWG or greater. But with light fixtures, manufacturers are permitted to use smaller sizes.  To be UL approved the fixtures are run with a megger to test the insulation.

Comment: No, because it's in an approved junction box.  If the logic was "the light can't draw more than 1A" that would justify thinner wires in the walls also, and actually there's a section on that in Code called the *tap rules*, however they are only applicable in industrial settings where 99.9% of the time the wiring is in metal conduit.  As an industrial guy, non-metallic cable in the walls I find kinda *scary*.

Comment: @DavidDoria presumably the designer of the fixture would know how much power could be used.  Also, light fixtures typically have labels on them saying "60W MAX BULB" or something similar to limit power draw (and heat in an enclosed fixture).